# How do I pass script-generated button array from one script to another in Unity C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I pass a button array made from a prefab with the following code which takes in a prefab of a button(TMPro) and then gives it a name and a text based on the iteretable value...

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class YearManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject scrollViewContent;

    private TextMeshProUGUI b1text;
    public GameObject buttonTemplate;

    public int initialYear = 1900;
    public int finalYear = 2023;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        for (int i = initialYear; i < finalYear; i++) {
            GameObject button = (GameObject)Instantiate(buttonTemplate);
            button.transform.SetParent(scrollViewContent.transform);
            button.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = i.ToString();
            button.name = i.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

... into any other Game Controller which accepts individual buttons instead of a button array.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dre32.png)

whose code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ScrollRectSnap_CS : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Public Variables
    public RectTransform panel; // To hold the ScrollPanel
    public Button[] bttn;
    public RectTransform center; // Center to compare the distance for each buttons

    // Private Variables
    private float[] distance; // All buttons' distance to the center
    private bool dragging = false; // Will be true while we drag the panel. Otherwise the UI will try to snap the button while dragging and pop
    private int bttnDistance; // Will hold the distance between the buttons
    private int minButtonNum; // Will hold the number of the buttons, with smallest distance to center

    void Start()
    {
        int bttnLength = bttn.Length;
        distance= new float[ bttnLength ]; //We are declaring the length of the distance, so we don't declare it dynamically which is more costly

        // Get distance between buttons
        bttnDistance = (int)Math.Abs(bttn[1].GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition.x - bttn[0].GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition.x);
        Debug.Log("Button Distance = " + bttnDistance);    
    }

    void Update()
    {
        for (int i=0; i<bttn.Length;i++) {
            distance[i] = Mathf.Abs(center.transform.position.x - bttn[i].transform.position.x); //Since we set the distance array to be the same as the button's array, we can use distance directly
        }

        float minDistance = Mathf.Min(distance); //Minimum number from the array of numbers

        for (int a = 0; a < bttn.Length; a++){ //Move through each of the distance
            if (minDistance == distance[a])
            { //If Button distance is same as the minimum distance 
                minButtonNum = a; //Number of buttons that have the smallest distance
            }
        }

        if (!dragging) {
            LerpToBttn(minButtonNum * -bttnDistance);
        }

    }

    void LerpToBttn(int position)
    {
        float newX = Mathf.Lerp(panel.anchoredPosition.x,position,Time.deltaTime*10f);
        Vector2 newPosition = new Vector2(newX,panel.anchoredPosition.y);

        panel.anchoredPosition = newPosition;
    }

    public void StartDrag() {
        dragging = true;
    }

    public void EndDrag() {
        dragging = false;
    }
}
```

I have tried simply putting the buttons in another array but didn't help.
I tried finding the button by it's number as ID that didn't help either.

I am trying to find a way so that the button array can be passed from one script to another.

Comment: Whenever you need to communicate between MonoBehaviours, the best way is to wrap your data into a class and pass it as an argument of the generic UnityEvent: `class MyButtons { public Button[] Buttons; }`, `class ButtonCollectionCreator { public UnityEvent<MyButtons> OnButtonsCreated; void Start() { ... OnButtonsCreated.Invoke(buttons)} }`. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75744703/how-to-use-events-in-unity-to-force-one-script-to-call-the-method-of-another-scr/75745293#75745293